# Flutter: Adding text from alert dialog to list view

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add user input from the alert dialog to list view. Every time I run it, the alert dialog accepts input and the item list gets updated but the list view wont update. The state of the app wont change after I press OK on the alert dialog button. Please help me with this issue as I'm new to flutter.

```
Future<String> createAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
        //promise to return string
        TextEditingController customController =
            TextEditingController(); //new texteditingc object
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Enter URL: "),
                content: TextField(
                  controller: customController,
                ),
                actions: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    child: Text("OK"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(customController.text.toString());
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
      }

  

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List item = List();
        item=['HI'];
        String temp;
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Shortie"),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListView(
              children: 
              
              item.map((element)=>Text(element)).toList(), 
              
              ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              createAlertDialog(context).then((onValue) {
                temp=onValue;
                print(temp);
                 
                
              });
              setState(() {
                item.add(temp);
                print(item);
              });
            },
            tooltip: 'Add URL',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        );
```

Comment: You want to show that entered URL in the list right?

Comment: yes I wanted to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call setState() in order to update a Widget if you have new information.

Try changing your `showDialog()` to this:

```dart
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Enter URL: "),
          content: TextField(
             controller: customController,
          ),
          actions: [
            MaterialButton(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                item.add(customController.text);
                setState((){});
                Navigator.of(context).pop();

            },
          )
        ],
      );
    });
```

That should add the element to the `item` list, update the widget and then pop. The timing between refresh and popping the dialog box is near instantaneous, so that should be smooth.

Furthermore, you might want to use `ListView.builder`, a class that will display a list that depends on the number of elements of the list of your choice.

With that said, changing the `ListView` to this could help in the future:

```dart
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: item.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text('${item.index}'),
        },
    ),
```

Comment: After making the above changes and restarting the app it works like a charm. Cheers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `await` instate of `then`. And make `item` as class property. Your List is not updating because every time you called setState the build function rebuild and the value of item set to ['HI'] because of `item=['HI']` this line.

Again when you use then function only the code inside of then function will execute when future will complete. That's why your setState called before your dialog finished.

Here I make some change of your code:

```
  List item = List();
  String temp;
  Future<String> createAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    //promise to return string
    TextEditingController customController =
        TextEditingController(); //new texteditingc object
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Enter URL: "),
            content: TextField(
              controller: customController,
            ),
            actions: [
              MaterialButton(
                elevation: 5.0,
                child: Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(customController.text.toString());
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    item = ['HI'];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Shortie"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: item.map((element) => Text(element)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          temp = await createAlertDialog(context);
          setState(() {
            item.add(temp);
            print(item);
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Add URL',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and communicate the `AlertDialog` with the `ListView` by using `notifyListeners()` and making the `ListView` a `Consumer` of the Provider data.

For more info about the package: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest